# CRM 2016 plugins firing inconsistently

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an entity with 4 plugins registered on the update message.

Two of the plugins are registered on the pre-operation pipeline stage and two of the plugins are registered asynchronously on the post-operation pipeline stage.  All four plugins have different filtering attributes.

Each of the plugins serializes its context to an xml file as soon as the Execute method is entered.  This is functionality baked into a base class we have and I have no reason to believe this would fail.

When testing the same record for an update I get inconsistent results.

Sometimes only the pre-operation pipeline plugins fire and sometimes all four plugins fire.

What is odd, is that I can tell by the value of the record I'm testing on, that all four plugins have fired.  However in many cases the serialized context file isn't generated

I've experimented with changing both of the async plugins to synchronous and that seems to temporarily fix the issue.  I've also experimented with disabling the pre-op plugins and only letting the async fire.

Has anyone dealt with a similar issue?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue; 1 thing to consider is that plugins will share some contextual items, so depending on how your base class is constructed, there may be some caching involved

Comment: See this MS article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx

Comment: I think this can only be answered by debugging the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the hell of debugging plugins. As a best pratice, I always suggest to have one plugin for one event and one entity. That way debuging is simpler and you can handle more complexe scenarios. Inside the plugin I check the target to know which field was updated.

As for your inconsistant results, it might be caused by the async steps. Did you configure the order in which they are triggered? By default, they are at 1. Which means random.